# Shall I use 'at' or 'in' or 'on' with a website?

Tags: prepositions, in-on-at

If I want to say something like

> I watch videos **at/in/on** MIT open courseware.

Shall I use 'at'/'in'/'on'?
More generally, when talking about websites, which one shall I use?

Comment: I'd say *on*, considdering 'MIT open courseware' as the platform on which you watch videos. You also watch videos **on YouTube**.

Comment: Somewhat related questions: [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3491/this-question-has-been-asked-at-stack-overflow-vs-on-stack-overflow) and [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8226/on-website-or-at-website)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to use "on" because when we are watching something on screen, using "on" is more appropriate.

Comment: Please be more elaborate. Unsourced claims may be downvoted or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

A website is an address so you watch at. Not on.