# Which preposition should be used for websites?

Tags: prepositions

Which prepositions should we use when we're talking about websites? For example:

Register **On** StackExchange / Register **AT** StackExchange

Trade **ON** Forex / Trade **AT** Forex

Answer questions **ON** Quora / Answer Questions **AT** Quora

Which one is correct?
Thanks

Comment: [Related question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62660/shall-i-use-at-or-in-or-on-with-a-website)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files are said to reside **on** a hard drive or **on** a certain machine. Since I know that a website is made of computer files, I think of a website as being on a machine and so any part of the website is also on that machine.

A website's "address" is a "Uniform Resource Locator" or URL. These terms connote the idea of website as "place". In this case the file would be at the website location.

So, if you think of a website as it is actually constructed (files stored on hard drives), you will probably say **on**.

If you think in the location metaphor, you will probably say **at**.

[Link to an answer for a related ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/8229)