# Is it "at" or "in" or "on" stack exchange?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, in-on-at

Could someone tell me which   is correct? is there an alternative?

Thank you.

> You are **at** Stack exchange site.
>
> You are **in** Stack exchange site.
>
> You are **on** Stack exchange site.

I checked this page https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/prepositions-place-at-in-on.htm and I think the correct is in.

in because you are inside a site/place.

Comment: @ColleenV how is a duplicate if they don't consider the 'in' as a choice?

Comment: If the answer specifically says it’s different from a physical location and says it should be “at”, why would you think it should be “in” or “atop” or “within” or any other word?

Comment: @ColleenV he does not address the 'in' case, and according to the first comment in that duplicated question, 'in'  can also be considered, but there must be a difference. Or is not correct?

Comment: I am trying to find you more related questions, but ran into technical difficulties since I’m on my phone. Here is another: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/62660/9161 If you click on [tag:in-on-at] it will list a number of questions related to choosing among them. “in Stack Exchange site” isn’t correct.

Comment: @ColleenV thanks. i'll say Smile! you are on --stack.exchange